# Date field is also giving me time

Tags: apex, visualforce, datetime, date

I am needing some help with a query that contains a date. I am collecting this date through a VF page with the help of a birthday fake contact field, my class is something like this:
**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class MyCLass {

public Contact fakeCont { get; set; }
public String queryString { get; set; }
public MyCLass() {
    fakeCont = new Contact();       
}

public void doQuery(){
    queryString = 'SELECT id, Name FROM SObject WHERE dateExample = ' + fakeCont.Birthdate  ; 
}
```

}

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!fakeCont.Birthdate}"/>
```

even that the field in contact is mark as date after selecting it displays something like
2014-11-02 00:00:00

it is not supposed to be displayed like: 2014-11-02 ?
as this field is date and not datetime?

if I try to use something like

`newDate = fakeCont.Birthdate.date();`

I will get an error

Answer (score 1):

If you [bind the date field](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) into the query rather than make it part of the query string you will avoid this problem. So your query string becomes:

```
 queryString = 'SELECT id, Name FROM SObject WHERE dateExample = :fakeCont.Birthdate';
```

Note that generally its better not to use strings in queries but instead make use of the compile-time checked static form:

```
Xyz__c[] sobs = [SELECT id, Name FROM Xyz__c WHERE DateField__c = :fakeCont.Birthdate];
```

Comment: Thank you, I also that I have another issue my field is dd/mm/yyyy and this one is yyyy-mm-dd, the only thing that I have found online to change the format is using something like: dateInitial.format('dd/MM/yyyy') however this seems to only works with datetime, how can i change this format when it is only date? Thanks

Comment: will be better to do it from the VF Page? curretnly I have 
<apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!fakeCont.Birthdate}"/>

Comment: ; actually I just realie that in the VF Page it displays correctly the problem is in the controller that it swaps the format

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a String to show the date use this:

```
String dateToShow = CustomObject.BdayDate__c.format();
```

It will take out the time (00:00:00);

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to show a date in your format

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy'-'MM'-'dd}">
    <apex:param value="{!fakeCont.Birthdate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```